# Desig considerations for a 10k va inverter

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, inverter

I want to design a 10kva dc-ac inverter. I have some experience with low power inverters, and I assume the working principles are similar, so I need to know if there are any considerations when it comes to high power design. In particular, is changing power MOSFETs and the transformer power rating enough? Or do I need to switch to a completely new design and use IGBTs instead of MOSFETs?

As an example, take a look at the following from TI ["800VA Pure Sine Wave Inverter's Reference Design - TI"](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa602/slaa602.pdf). Can I just change the MOSFETs to CSD18536KTT and use higher power transformers to change the design to a 10kva one?

Comment: Which voltage ?

Comment: I haven't looked in detail at this, but essentially yes - however don't forget to check the FET drivers are man enough for beefier FETS;  heat-sinks, wire sizes etc will all need to be up-rated, and sense circuitry will need modifying.

Comment: @matzeri 110 AC. Flexible on the input voltage, since I can use any battery pack, but let's say 12VDC.

Comment: 10,000W / 12 VDC ~= 830A. Not likely.Wire, PCB, devices, ... .-> Hard.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I just change the MOSFETs to CSD18536KTT and use higher power
>   transformers to change the design to a 10kva one?

The original 800 VA TI design uses 4 x MOSFETs (in a H bridge) with absolute maximum ratings of 40 V and 100 A. Assuming that the 40 V rating was adequate for a 12 V battery, to get an output of 800 VA means a current of 67 A from the battery so, a rating of 100 A for the MOSFETs seems adequate.

The new MOSFETs you propose have ratings of 60 V and 200 A. Given that you could now power them from an 18 volt battery (because the voltage rating is larger) and, given that 200 A derates to 133 amps (using the same derating as the TI design), the output power from these devices is, on the face of it, limited to 18 V x 133 A = 2400 VA.

This likely means that you will need 4 or 5 times the number of transistors to achieve 10 kVA.

Yes, you'll certainly need higher power transformers.

Comment: Isn't that TI design valid for up to 3 kVA? (See figure 2)

Comment: 800 watts from a 12 V battery means switching currents of 67 amps. The devices are rated at 100 amps so unless the design uses parallel combinations of MOSFETs I'd say 800 watts is about the limit when using 4x CSD18502 devices.